# Jasmine: a function is called instead to be replaced by andReturn()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a very simple function that needs to be tested: it returns an object and works fine at runtime.
Most of the fields of such object are fixed, but one of them changes according the result of a function: `checkWeather.getWeather().`

In Unit Tests (Jasmine): `checkWeather.getWeather()` is spied by `spyOn(...).andReturn(FIXEDVALUE)`, so that it will return the result i want. But when the test is run, this function returns 'NOT_INITIALIZED', that means that it wasn't initialized. But, since we have andReturn, we just should get a result, and the function shouldn't be called at all; during testing, it should be replaced by FIXEDVALUE.

Please see the comments in the code, maybe it will be more clear.

Can you see my error in the testing code, and why the behaviour is so strange? (The first file works perfectly, just i need to write the unit test, and that is not working).

---

### weather.js (this is correctly working on runtime)

```
function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('weatherModule')
        .service('TEST_ME', TEST_ME);

    TEST_ME.$inject = ['FILTER_TYPE', 'checkWeather', 'values'];

    function TEST_ME(FILTER_TYPE, checkWeather, values) {
// when this next is called by JASMINE, checkWeather.getWeather() returns 'NOT_INITIALIZED'
//but during testing I expect getWeather() to return VALUE as specified in .andReturn(VALUE) - see following file
    console.log("checkWeather.getWeather(): ", checkWeather.getWeather());

        return {
            today: {
                name: "today",
                //Under Jasmine, the next condition will always be false
                isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

---

### weather-TEST.js

```
'use strict';

describe('TEST_ME', function () {
    var TEST_ME;
    var checkWeather;
    var values;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('weatherModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ( _TEST_ME_, _checkWeather_, _values_) {
        TEST_ME = _TEST_ME_;
        checkWeather = _checkWeather_;
        values = _values_;
    }));

    describe('Not fixed parts of TEST_ME', function () {
        it('should sunny', function () {

            var sunToday_TEST_ME = {
                isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
             }
            };

            spyOn(checkWeather, 'getWeather').andReturn(values.sunToday);
            //The next works!! It prints the value values.sunToday set by .andReturn()
            console.log("In UT, checkWeather.getWeather(): ", checkWeather.getWeather());
            expect(TEST_ME.today.isSunny).toEqual(sunToday_TEST_ME.isSunny);
    }); // This fails :(
});
```

I am loosing a lot of time by writing this unit test, much more than to write the whole feature! Can you see where is my error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly checkWeather is... In my opinion you need something like a WeatherService which has the function getWeather. From the code you provided the function getWeather is not defined anywhere, so it will always be undefined. Maybe you can share some more code to better understand what exactly are you trying to test

Comment: Do you  really need two `beforeEach()`. Do you intend to use `beforeAll()` by any chance?

Comment: hello,
checkWeather is a service, it's injected, but maybe i don't do it in the right way...
Anyway, it seems that "unkonwn" is one of the values that such service can return; like if the callFake is ignored. I will continue to investigate, and also wait for answers.

Answer (score 1):

### As factory

*I've implemented *TEST_ME** as **factory** as long as factory in AngularJS can return anything and we need closure here to store value of injected service `checkWeather`.

In `beforeEach` under test where you are going assign `TEST_ME = _TEST_ME_;` the function TEST_ME receives dependent values. That place is to early for that as spies are not setup yet. So, I decide to return function from factory and execute it in the test.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('weatherModule', [])
    .factory('TEST_ME', TEST_ME);

  TEST_ME.$inject = ['FILTER_TYPE', 'checkWeather', 'values'];

  function TEST_ME(FILTER_TYPE, checkWeather, values) {
    return function() {
      return {
        today: {
          name: "today",
          isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
        }
      };
    }
  }
}());

describe('weatherModule', function() {
  var TEST_ME, checkWeather, values

  beforeEach(module('weatherModule'))

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('weatherModule')
      .value('FILTER_TYPE', '')
      .value('checkWeather', {
        getWeather: function() {}
      })
      .value('values', {
        SUNNY: true
      })
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function(_TEST_ME_, _checkWeather_, _values_) {
    TEST_ME = _TEST_ME_;
    checkWeather = _checkWeather_;
    values = _values_;
  }));

  describe('The day is', function() {
    it('sunny when `checkWeather.getWeather` return true', function() {
      spyOn(checkWeather, 'getWeather').and.returnValue(true);
      expect(TEST_ME().today.isSunny).toEqual(true);
    });
    
    it('ugly when `checkWeather.getWeather` return false', function() {
      spyOn(checkWeather, 'getWeather').and.returnValue(false);
      expect(TEST_ME().today.isSunny).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<link href="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

### As service and postponed initialization:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('weatherModule', [])
    .service('TEST_ME', TEST_ME);

  TEST_ME.$inject = ['FILTER_TYPE', 'checkWeather', 'values'];

  function TEST_ME(FILTER_TYPE, checkWeather, values) {
    this.today = {
      name: "today",
      isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
    }
  }
}());

describe('weatherModule', function() {
  var TEST_ME, instatiateService, checkWeather, values

  beforeEach(module('weatherModule'))

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('weatherModule')
      .value('FILTER_TYPE', '')
      .value('checkWeather', {
        getWeather: jasmine.createSpy('foo')
      })
      .value('values', {
        SUNNY: true
      })
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function(_checkWeather_, _values_, $injector) {
    checkWeather = _checkWeather_;
    values = _values_;
    instatiateService = function() {
      return $injector.get('TEST_ME')
    }
  }));

  describe('The day is', function() {
    it('sunny when `checkWeather.getWeather` returns true', function() {
      checkWeather.getWeather.and.returnValue(true)
      TEST_ME = instatiateService()
      expect(TEST_ME.today.isSunny).toEqual(true);
    });

    it('ugly when `checkWeather.getWeather` return false', function() {
      checkWeather.getWeather.and.returnValue(false)
      TEST_ME = instatiateService()
      expect(TEST_ME.today.isSunny).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<link href="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks
I implemented the second solution. The good is that it worked, the bad is that other tests where getWeather was called, now are failing.
It's like the function, spied in this way, is changed for ALL tests, not only the current one...

Comment: You can move spy creation from beforeEach to the `it`. In the beforeEach assign function to `getWeather` than add spy to it in the test.

Answer (score 0):

finally I changed the architecture of the service to make it testable.
For some reasons due to teh system, it was not possible (or very difficult) to call spyOn().andReturn() before the object was created. So I added the possibility to refresh the values and they would be set using the spied function.

Previously, TEST_ME was very confortable to be used, because it was enough to use the object in this way: TEST_ME.xxx.
Now, it's necessary to do TEST_ME.getWeatherConditions().xxx.

But who cares, i changed all the calls to TEST_ME.xxx → TEST_ME.getWeatherConditions().xxx
And now it's more testable

---

### weather.js

```
function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('weatherModule')
        .service('TEST_ME', TEST_ME);

    TEST_ME.$inject = ['FILTER_TYPE', 'checkWeather', 'values'];

    function TEST_ME(FILTER_TYPE, checkWeather, values) {
    var conditions = null;
    //the rest of the project doesn't know that this need to be done, so do it during creation.
    updateWeatherConditions();  //the rest of the project doesn't know that this need to be done, so do it during creation.

    return {
        updateWeatherConditions: updateWeatherConditions,
        getWeatherConditions: getWeatherConditions
    };

    function getWeatherConditions() {
        return conditions;
    }
    //Using this function i can update the result whenever I want
    function updateWeatherConditions() {
        conditions = {
            today: {
                name: "today",
                //Every time we call getWeatherConditions, the return value is refreshed
                isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
            }
        };
        }
    }
})();
```

---

### weather-TEST.js

```
'use strict';

describe('TEST_ME', function () {
    var TEST_ME;
    var checkWeather;
    var values;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('weatherModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ( _TEST_ME_, _checkWeather_, _values_) {
        TEST_ME = _TEST_ME_;
        checkWeather = _checkWeather_;
        values = _values_;
    }));

    describe('Not fixed parts of TEST_ME', function () {
        it('should sunny', function () {

            var sunToday_TEST_ME = {
                isSunny: checkWeather.getWeather() === values.SUNNY
             }
            };

            spyOn(checkWeather, 'getWeather').andReturn(values.sunToday);
            // I don't care if conditions were created before spyOn() - i refresh them now
            TEST_ME.updateWeatherConditions();

            expect(TEST_ME.getWeatherConditions().today.isSunny).toEqual(sunToday_TEST_ME.isSunny);
    });
});
```